# Code 400 while sending JSON from android using URLConnection

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting code 400 when I am trying to send data to my server. Here is my Async Task where post method is called. When i am using get method it is displaying the result correctly but with post it gives bad connection error !

```
private class PutData extends AsyncTask<Object , Void , String>
{
    String habitsUrl = "http://donow-app.herokuapp.com/habits.json";
    int responseCode = -1;
    String responseData;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params)
    {
        try
        {
            URL habits = new URL(habitsUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) habits.openConnection();
            connection.addRequestProperty("x-user-email" , email);
            connection.addRequestProperty("x-user-token" , "WieLmf2DVKpsAPzgN7HA");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.connect();
            //connection.setDoOutput(true);
            //connection.setUseCaches(true);
            responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                jsonParam.put("habit[title]", "Hello");
                Log.v(TAG , jsonParam.toString());
                DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                //Log.v(TAG, (jsonParam.toString()));
                System.out.print(jsonParam.toString());
                printout.write(jsonParam.toString().getBytes());
                printout.flush();
                printout.close();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i(TAG , "Code" + responseCode);
            }


        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseData;
    }

}
```

Please help me remove this error. I have tried all the possibilities but wasnt able to figure out my mistake.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't a problem with your Android code. It's a problem with your server. What's intended to happen when you send a POST request to that endpoint?

Comment: I am trying to send "hello" value to my key "title" of "habit" inside my database.